# Аутентификация на сайте посредством смарт-карты или аналога

Tags: веб-программирование, http, безопасность, nfc

Здравствуйте, местное население!

Небольшая предыстория: работаю в оперном театре, и там есть расписание выходов на работу. Длиннющее на 2,5 стенда на весь оркестр. БУМАЖНОЕ! Помимо кучи минусов у него есть один самый главный: чтобы на него посмотреть (а то и увидеть что-то новое) - нужно приехать из дома в театр. И я уже второй месяц, наверное, думаю, написать сайт с расписанием, разными уровнями доступа, блекджеком и женщинами тяжелого характера. И это для меня - как нефиг. Недели 2-3 неспешной работы.

Но хотелось бы добавить больше удобства (помимо мобильных приложенек на 3 самые распространенные ОСи) - добавить аутентификацию посредством карты/брелка/чего-нибудь еще. По факту, все, что мне нужно - это получить id и token.

На данный момент я завис на выборе между NFC и ISO 7816 (карта с чипом, как у симки). Первое дешевле, а второе лучше работает по плану "карта вставлена - работаем, карту достали - только просмотр с никаким доступом".

Единственное, что меня останавливает - я понятия не имею, как это сделать. Веб-языки здесь не помогут, а в системном программировании я не шарю, поэтому хочу у вас спросить: **в какие языки копать, и есть ли готовые решения**? Нужно наладить связь между сайтом (на стороне клиента) и считывателем с возможностью считывания и передачи на сервер и программирования (если есть полномочия). Гуглом пользовался, но мне не помогло :(

Заранее спасибо! :3

Comment: Не усложняйте. В интернет-банк и то можно зайти без смарт-карты. А вы хотите заставить музыкантов использовать сложное техническое средство. Разве это удобно?

Comment: Не, я захотел nfc или rfid или iso7816 не потому, что это офигеть как круто, а потому что, подойдя к стенду, не очень-то удобно вводить логин/пароль...

Comment: А про мобильные приложеньки - это специально для интеграции с гуглокалендарем, напоминалок, установки будильника (если утренняя репетиция (в 10. Сегодня вечеров поставили, а завтра в 10 утра надо быть)), да и люди слишком ленивые, чтобы заходить в браузер и вводить урл. Им проще нажать на приложеньку. Хотя мне, как исключительно веб-прогеру, намного проще без них - мне не нужно будет учить на кое-каком примитивном уровне несколько языков

Comment: Предлагаю вам [перенести разговор в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56969/discussion-on-question-by-lenald------).

Comment: Пока стенд - доска на стене, но если я сделаю сайт даже без карт доступа, и руководство согласится - расщедрятся на вертикальные большие мониторы. Подключенные к какому-нибудь системнику/датацентру

Comment: Будет слишком сложно для данной задачи. Музыканты потеряют тут же брелки, карты и все окажется ненужным. Приложений достаточно.